# bash or bash_profile JAVA_HOME permanent export

Tags: java, linux, bash

I tried to export JAVA, used this

```
JAVA_HOME=/etc/jdk1.7.0_07/
export JAVA_HOME
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

It seems like it works just for while, after I close my console have to do this again.. How to install it permanently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@AdamSiemion is close - You should add these lines to `~/.bashrc`, which is sourced by **interactive shells**, while `~/.bash_profile` is only sourced by **interactive login shells**.

```
cat >> ~/.bashrc <<'EOF'
JAVA_HOME=/etc/jdk1.7.0_07/
export JAVA_HOME
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
EOF
```

To verify, open a new shell and `echo "$JAVA_HOME"`.

Comment: I'm sorry for it. I meant if I have the same problems ocur What I need just add that type of commands to bashrc. Just the reason why I ask because I have Maven - this is tool which manage progects it also was issue like this.

Comment: It depends on the tool. While I'm not familiar with Maven configuration, the manual should describe what you need to do to have the appropriate environment variables available.

Answer (score 0):

Append these lines to the `.bash_profile` file in your `HOME` directory, i.d. `~/.bash_profile`.